# Have to press Fn+Alt+Volume up/down keyboard shortcut after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, macbook, shortcut-keys

My <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Volume up</kbd>/<kbd>Volume down</kbd> key on a MacBook Pro late 2011 used to be functional as usual in Ubuntu 13.10. After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, I have to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Volume up</kbd>/<kbd>Volume down</kbd> keyboard combination to do the same. The weird thing is when I set this function in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Sound and media, I only push <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Volume up</kbd>/<kbd>Volume down</kbd>. It sets the key binding correctly without <kbd>Alt</kbd> while not working with the <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that an incorrect string is set in `dconf` key:

Original (working) value:

```
~$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up
'XF86AudioRaiseVolume'
```

After running "unity-control-center keyboard", and setting the shortcut for
volume-up key:

```
~$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up
'AudioRaiseVolume'
```

The new value misses the "XF86" part of the string, and does not work.

You can get the key working again by resetting the value, with:

```
~$ gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up
~$ gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down
```

The bug already reported:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1302885