# How to get AZIO L70 Volume knob to work

Tags: 14.04

I purchased an AZIO backlit L70 today, volume control is not working.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/469791/14-04-thinkpad-edge-volume-buttons-stopped-working/470103#470103

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: What have you tried already?  Is it a USB device?  PS/2?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to up vote this is the solution, but I don't have enough points to!

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-mute
```

That solution comes from:
[14.04 ThinkPad Edge volume buttons stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469791/14-04-thinkpad-edge-volume-buttons-stopped-working/470103#470103)

Comment: Those commands worked great, but I just wanted to add that anyone using Linux *inside a Virtual Box VM* will also need to add an exception for the keyboard in the Virtual Box USB settings.